# Ajustar imagem Retrato para Paisagem CSS

Tags: html, css

Quando a imagem é paisagem, o thumbnail fica top. Quando é retrato, a função não ajusta para que permaneça em modo paisagem ajustando a imagem com as devidas proporções.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico em INSPECIONAR código, este é o CSS que está trabalhando a imagem:

```
element.style {
}

.add-image a img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
.no-margin {
    margin: 0!important;
}
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: border .2s ease-in-out;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: e se as imagens fossem quadradas?

Answer (score -1):

usando apenas CSS dá para centrar e cortar uma imagem do seguinte modo:

```
.thumbnail {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

<div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');"></div>
```